# Count cases by dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a question related to mysql:

I had a table called "datelist" listed all of the dates from 2011 to 2017. And I got another table "sqltest" having two columns "start_date" and "end_date",showing the product active using date information. These two columns were datetime type variables, eg: 2016-02-17 21:52:26.594847.

And I want to count how much cases are active use in each date from 2011 to 2017.

And I am new in mysql, and could someone guide me how to deal with such issue?

Appreciate!

Comment: what you have tried? can we get some example data and a expected output?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch My own thinking is that to select the cases between start_date and end_date day by day.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch And I want the expected output to be a table which listed the count of the active use cases by date from 2011 to 2017 ( all dates)

Comment: For best results on Stack Overflow, when you ask how to create a query, you should provide a few rows of sample data and a few rows of the result you want.

Comment: If you have the date on these format, use substr(start_date, 0, 10). You can use this on select, while clause or even group by.

Answer (score 1):

Without data from you, we have to guess from the clues supplied in a brief question. We know there are 2 tables and 2 column names are mentioned, but the column name(s) in the second table are unknown. There is a difference of time precision implied by the question, but that isn't verified by sample data.

I imagine that the reason for mentioning the time precision is so that some compensation is made in the query to ensure that any test that is active on a day is recorded. e.g that the date 2016-02-17 records a test starting at 2016-02-17 21:52:26.594847

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE sqltest
    (`start_date` datetime, `end_date` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO sqltest
    (`start_date`, `end_date`)
VALUES
    ('2016-02-17 21:52:26', '2016-02-27 21:52:26')
;


CREATE TABLE datelist
    (`a_date` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO datelist
    (`a_date`)
VALUES
    ('2016-02-01 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-02 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-03 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-04 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-05 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-06 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-07 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-08 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-09 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-10 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-11 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-12 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-13 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-14 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-15 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-16 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-17 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-18 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-19 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-20 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-21 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-22 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-23 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-24 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-25 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-26 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-27 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-28 00:00:00'),
    ('2016-02-29 00:00:00')
;
```

Sample Query

```
select
      d.a_date
    , count(t.start_date)
from datelist d
left join sqltest t on d.a_date between DATE_SUB(t.start_date,INTERVAL 1 DAY)  and t.end_date
group by
      d.a_date
;
```